# No such relation 'Profile' on entity 'User'

Tags: soql, profile, user

I'm running the following SOQL query:

```
SELECT Profile.Name, Title FROM User WHERE Id = '<some id>'
```

Most of the times it works fine, but for some users I get the following error (I guess it's because the token I'm using doesn't have the permissions for the `Profile` object)

```
No such relation 'Profile' on entity 'User'
```

Is there a way to craft the query to return `Profile.Name` only when `Profile` is supported, and to return NULL (or similar) when we have no permissions to `Profile`?

Comment: I am expecting such queries to be made by Admins, in which case it shouldn't be a problem of permissions. :)

Comment: @MahmoodButt why? I'm running this query using the token of the user I'm requesting the information for.

Comment: Well in that case you do have a problem. You cant achieve this task with just SOQL then.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this permissions error by changing your query to be dependent upon the current user's permissions:

```
if (Schema.sObjectType.Profile.isAccessible()) {
   u = [SELECT Profile.Name, Title FROM User WHERE Id = '<some id>'];
} else {
   u = [SELECT Title FROM User WHERE Id = '<some id>'];
}
```

This is some basic code to get you moving. You could use the same if logic and write the query dynamically.

### EDIT

You mentioned that the call is being made using the REST API. You could take the code I have written above and create an ApexREST method that you call instead of making your Query via the REST API. This is still RESTful, uses only a slightly modified endpoint and for yourself ensures that the code calling the service need not know this information in advance.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my code runs outside of SF and is using the REST API to run the query. I know I can solve it with two separate SOQL queries, however I wonder if this is doable with only one query.

Comment: Just edited the answer - make the code i wrote an ApexREST endpoint and you are good to go.